# Hold funds for a time period with no possibility of contract's owner/author stealing them

Tags: security

if I write an EOS smart contract such that party A can send EOS to party B, but the contract will hold the funds for (say) 48 hours before releasing them to party B, can I do this in a way that would prevent the contract creator, who holds the private key to the contract, from withdrawing (stealing) the EOS during the time that it's being held?  The contract creator is neither party A nor B.

Any pointers to code, or suggestions about which features of the language/environment might help with this problem would be very helpful to this newbie!

Thanks in advance!